# Hierarchical query with some joins

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I am struggling to write a performing query which would consist of the data from one sub-select, and hierarchically retrieved data from another table based on the rows from that first sub-select.

So, I have some data retrieved from multiple tables with joins, which finally boils down to the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TBL1 (UUID, MiscData, KeyToLookup, ConditionClause ) AS
SELECT  13, 'ATM',             12345, null                  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 447, 'Balance Inquiry', 67890, 'BALANCE_INQUIRY_FEE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 'Credit',          22321, 'CREDIT_FEE'          FROM DUAL;
```

Now, I have another table which stores the hierarchical structure of fees:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TBL2 ( TariffDomainID, FeeType, UpperTariffDomainID, ID ) AS
SELECT 1543, 'WHATEVER_FEE',         154, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1543, 'BALANCE_INQUIRY_FEE',  154, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  154, 'SMTHELSE_FEE',          15, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  154, 'CREDIT_FEE',            15, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   15, 'BALANCE_INQUIRY_FEE', null, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

And there is a way to link the first selection to the lowest row in hierarchy of the second table, there are few joins but finally it's like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TBL3 ( ID, FirstTblKey, SecondTblKey ) AS
SELECT 1, 67890, 1543 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 22321, 1543 FROM DUAL;
```

The important point is that it's not guaranteed there will be a row with this `KeyToLookup` directly in the second table, as directed by the `TBL3`.
E.g. in the example above:

row `TBL1.UUID=789` is linked via `TBL3` to `TBL2` row with `TariffDomainID=1543`,
but there is no row in `TBL2` with `TariffDomainID=1543` and `FeeType=CREDIT_FEE`;

however `TBL2` contains a link to the same table but upper level, `UpperTariffDomainID=154`,
and there **is** a row in `TBL2` with `TariffDomainID=154` and `FeeType=CREDIT_FEE`.

In the end I need to connect the info from `TBL1` with the all occurrences of this key in `TBL2` hierarchically, numerated by depth of hierarchy.

So I expect to get this:

```
| UUID |     MiscData    | KeyToLookup |   ConditionClause   | TariffDomainIDWithPresence | Depth |
|------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------|----------------------------|-------|
| 13   | ATM             |    12345    | null                |            null            |  null |
| 447  | Balance Inquiry |    67890    | BALANCE_INQUIRY_FEE |            1543            |   1   |
| 447  | Balance Inquiry |    67890    | BALANCE_INQUIRY_FEE |            15              |   3   |
| 789  | Credit          |    22321    | CREDIT_FEE          |            154             |   2   |
```

Could anyone please teach me how to make such a hierarchical query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query joined to the other two tables:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.uuid,
       t1.miscdata,
       t1.keytolookup,
       t1.conditionclause,
       t2.tariffdomainid,
       t2.depth
FROM   tbl1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 t3
       ON ( t1.keytolookup = t3.firsttblkey )
       OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT tariffdomainid,
                LEVEL AS depth
         FROM   tbl2 t2
         WHERE  t2.tariffdomainid = t3.secondtblkey
         START WITH
                t2.feetype = t1.conditionclause
         CONNECT BY
                PRIOR TariffDomainID = UpperTariffDomainID
       ) t2
ORDER BY
       uuid,
       depth
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> ```
> UUID | MISCDATA        | KEYTOLOOKUP | CONDITIONCLAUSE     | TARIFFDOMAINID | DEPTH
> ---: | :-------------- | ----------: | :------------------ | -------------: | ----:
>   13 | ATM             |       12345 | null                |           null |  null
>  447 | Balance Inquiry |       67890 | BALANCE_INQUIRY_FEE |           1543 |     1
>  447 | Balance Inquiry |       67890 | BALANCE_INQUIRY_FEE |           1543 |     3
>  789 | Credit          |       22321 | CREDIT_FEE          |           1543 |     2
> ```

*(Note: you need the `DISTINCT` as there are multiple 1543 and 154 entries in `TBL2` so the hierarchical query can take multiple paths to get from the start to the end condition. If your actual data does not have these duplicates then you should be able to remove the `DISTINCT` clause.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4e68db129efac172be75b7fa5057dad)*

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to verify the proposed solution but something must be off as the query is not finishing in reasonable time. I will get back with this once I return to work on Sunday.

Comment: I was able to adjust the script to be used in the real scenario I had using the technique you showed. Thanks a lot for your help!